# Jquery/JSON Not doing what I want

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I am using .getJSON and returning a JSON object that I want to use an if statement to see what it is, and then do a specific function.
Some examples of the JSON object getting passed in are:

```
{ "action" : [ { "seated" : "player6", "action" : "check", "bet": "" } ] } 

{ {"turn" : [ { "card" : "30", } ] } 

{ "action" : [ { "seated" : "player8", "action" : "raise", "bet": "18000" } ] } 

{ {"flop" : [ { "card" : "33", "card" : "22", "card" : "40" } ] }
```

My getJson function is this:

```
$.getJSON('/gmae/action', 

function(action) {
    if (action.flop) {
        setCard(0, action.flop[0].card);
        setCard(1, action.flop[1].card);
        setCard(2, action.flop[2].card);
        alert("inflop")
    }
    if (action.action) {
        setAction(action.action[0].seated, action.action[0].action, action.action[0].bet);
    }
    if (action.flop) {
        setCard(0, action.flop[0].card);
        setCard(1, action.flop[1].card);
        setCard(2, action.flop[2].card);
        alert("inflop")
    }
    else if (action.turn) {
        setCard(3, action.turn[0].card);
    }
    else if (action.river) {
        setCard(4, action.river[0].card);
    }
    else if (action.newhand) {
        window.location.href=window.location.href;
    }

}
```

If any of the "action"s are called it works fine and goes into the correct function.  However if flop turn or river are the actions called from the JSON file then nothing happens.  Does anyone have any idea why this is happening?

Comment: Note the leading { {  in turn and flop

Comment: turn and flop are invalid jsons http://www.jsonlint.com/

Comment: Very good call!  Im going to investigate that.

Comment: Use http://jsonlint.com to evaluate your syntax if you are stuck on a problem like this. It is very helpful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have one extra `{` in TURN and FLOP JSONs! Notice it? Here's how it should be:

```
 {"turn" : [ { "card" : "30", } ] } 

 {"flop" : [ { "card" : "33", "card" : "22", "card" : "40" } ] }
```